# Azure VM Endpoint Allow All or Deny All by Default?

Tags: azure

I have setup an http endpoint (port 80) for my Azure VM. I have verified that the firewall is allowing port 80 both in and out. (My VM operating system is Windows Server 2012.)

Yet still, I am unable to hit IIS on port 80 from a remote machine. (Locally I can hit localhost just fine.)

So I'm wondering if what I'm missing is a network acl. However, [the Azure documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-acl/) (as of 12/2/2013) seems contradictory:

> When a virtual machine is created, a default ACL is put in place to
>   block all incoming traffic. However, if an endpoint is created for
>   (port 3389), then the default ACL is modified to **allow all** inbound
>   traffic for that endpoint.

Yet below it says:

> It’s important to note that by default, when an endpoint is created,
>   **all traffic is denied** to the endpoint.

Which is correct? Do I need to create an allow all ACL? Am I missing something else about how Azure DNS and network traffic works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That same page follows on to write

> No ACL – By default when an endpoint is created, we permit all for the
>   endpoint.

I believe that the comment suggesting all traffic is denied by default is wrong.

To confirm I have just deployed a brand new Windows Server 2012 Data Centre VM, installed IIS, open the Windows Firewall and configured an endpoint for TCP port 80 and it all worked just fine although its worth pointing out that it took a few minutes between configuring the endpoint and being able to browse to the server.

Comment: Thanks. So let me look at what might be different for me.

Comment: It looks like my Azure instance was corrupted. Probably because I previously had a VM of the same dns name that I deleted. I created a new VM with a different dns name. That worked. Not sure if the dns name was the issue or if the instance was just in a bad state. But creating a new VM "solved" the problem.

Comment: me to, it is quite weird, just creating a new one, enable firewall, problem "solved"